# When おばあさん is not really your grandmother

Tags: meaning

When native speakers of Japanese use おばあさん to refer to an older woman who is not that that individual's own grandmother, does their *concept* of the woman include any expectation that she would have had children at some point during her life?

Comment: Chinese has an analogous usage of the word for "grandmother" (perhaps the Japanese calqued it from Chinese?); the "grandmother" is most likely with children simply due to age, but to me, a Mandarin native speaker, the question of whether the old woman has any children would not enter my mind *at all*.

Comment: In Chinese, "that old grandmother" is used extremely generally to mean "that old woman". In fact, "that old woman" reeks of awkwardness and CSL.

Comment: Asking for answers from "native speakers" is superfluous. Information is either correct or not, regardless of source. The request only makes the asker seem hostile to non-native sources which could be potentially be helpful in ways that native speakers can't be. Not to mention that anyone on this site can claim to be a native speaker when giving an answer, but there is no way of verifying that.

Comment: @DaveMG, I'm sorry. If I'm asking a grammar or vocab question, I don't care about the source...  For this particular question, my preference is to pick the minds of native speakers. I do this not out of hostility towards non-Japanese in general but out of a desire to circumvent speculation when I want understand the *concept* in the mind of native speakers.

Comment: @virmaior, I appreciate you that you meant no offense, but I think you need to trust that what you're after is the default assumption of all questions on this site. Everyone wants to avoid idle speculation from uninformed sources, and everyone wants to know how native speakers conceptualize their words. A non-native speaker may have got the correct information from a native speaker, and is now able to not only pass that on to you, but also do so in a more accessible way because they can frame the information in terms that make more sense to a learner.

Comment: @DaveMG. I've edited the question to express that what I want to understand is a native speaker's *concept* and thus derefenced any question about the identity of the answerer.

Comment: @virmaior, nice. Thanks for your understanding. `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, yes, there is that assumption in our minds, but this custom rarely, if ever, causes problems when the older woman addressed as おばあさん by a stranger actually turns out to be someone who has never had a child in her life.  That is because it is likely that she herself has been addressing any older lady おばあさん since she was little.

Comment: I can't imagine a woman ever being offended at the term おばあさん based on whether or not she's had children. Far more important is whether or not she feels she's too young for the term. But more importantly, doesn't every culture default to assume that people above a certain age have led a life that includes the expecation of having had children? I'm not sure if the use of おばあさん conveys anything particular that isn't assumed in just about every language.

Comment: @DaveMG, regarding the larger expectation, part of why I bothered asking is that while we do have the term "granny" in English, it is a slightly derogatory term to say about random older women whereas おばあさん is the common term. Moreover, in contemporary English (at least American English), I wouldn't assume "older woman" means she had children at this point in time.